# How to change default "create next app" in Next js 13

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I am not able to change the default "Create Next App" title from the webpage in Next js 13 . I read their docs about

next/head and how to use but it doesnt seem to work . I am new to this framework pls help

Tried changing default title in next js 13 but nothing happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is really easy to do in NEXT JS 13.

**For Static Routes -**

In your *page.tsx* file **create and export** a new **variable** `metadata`

```
export const metadata = {
  title: "My new title",
  description: "My description",
}
```

**For Dynamic Routes -**

In your *page.tsx* file **create and export** a new **function** `generateMetadata()`. You can also access the `id` of the **dynamic route**.

```
export async function generateMetadata({params}: {params: { id: string }}) {
  return(
    title: `page ${params.id}`,
  )
}
```

If the code above feels hard to read, that's because of `typescript`.

Anyways I'd recommmend you to watch this video by Vercel - https://youtu.be/gSSsZReIFRk?t=702

It was really helpful for me! Hope it helps you too!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```js
import Head from 'next/head'

function IndexPage() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>My page title</title>
      </Head>
      <p>Hello world!</p>
    </div>
  )
}

export default IndexPage
```

Place your title tag within the Next Head component. See the  [documentation for more info](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/head)

Comment: I did this earlier (following the docs) but it still isn't working

Comment: Paste the relevant code in your question

Answer (score 0):

> ### head.js (deprecated)
>
> Instead of using a special head.js file, metadata can be set directly inside a layout.js or page.js file by exporting a static metadata object or dynamic generateMetadata function

take a look [here](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/file-conventions/head)

so what you have to do is to put the `<title>` element directly inside your JSX :

```js
export default function Home() {
  return (
    <main className={styles.main}>
       <title>My Title</title>
      //...
    </main>
  )
```

Comment: can you also help what should i write so that i can change the title favicon , like for title title: is used but what about images ?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out , i just had to change metadata in layout.jsx

Answer (score 0):

Don't add  component

just add the page.tsx on top

```
type Props = {}

export const metadata = {
    title: "Page title",
    description: "**",
}

export default function HomePage({}: Props) {
  return (
    <main >
        /** code */
    </main>
  )
}
```